# How to exclude components from javascript onkeydown

Tags: javascript, html

Is is possible?

In my page I got

`<body onload="debug()" id="content" onkeydown="checkKey()" >`

and

```
function checkKey() {
    if ((window.event.keyCode > 9) || (window.event.keyCode < 9)) {
        document.actionForm.saveStatus.value = "Not saved";
    }
}
```

But I don't want this to happen when the user just goes to the page and uses the search form to submit a search unless session data was saved first so I want to exclude events from the searchbox for the checkkey():

```
<input onkeypress="javascript:searchWithEnter('Oversikt','fastsearch')" title="Nummerformat:

PCT/SE2009/123456
PCTSE2009123456
PSE09123456

ITS/SE09/12345
ITSSE0912345
ISE0912345

1234567-8
12345678" type="text" size="40" name="fastsearch">
    <input type="button" value="Sök" onclick="javascript:doSubmitFastSearch('Oversikt','fastsearch')">
```

Should I just remove the onkeypress from the body tag and set checkkey() to get called from individual components instead? What do you propose?

Comment: Isn't `((window.event.keyCode > 9) || (window.event.keyCode < 9))` equal to `(window.event.keyCode != 9)`? Use focused or visible items to bind an such an event instead of body!

Comment: @Vishal So I should remove the `onkeypressed` from the body tag and make calls using javascript onchange at individual components instead? I didn't write the checkkey function and I don't know what keyCode 9 is but the answer to what you're asking might very well be yes. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Yes! that's perfect, use javascript; However you'll have to rethink on binding events. If its just a searchbox to exclude you can simply do that but if there is a possibility of further exclusion, you'll need to use `class` or `tagname` for the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`event.stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.stopPropagation) to stop the event to bubbling to `<body/>`.

```
var stop = function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
};
var $el = document.getElementsByName("fastsearch")[0];
$el.onkeydown = stop;
```

But, unless strictly necessary, you should consider not binding so recklessly events to `<body/>`.